# Defining stored type properties on classes

Tags: swift

I'm a Swift rookie and found myself confused when reading this paragraph from "The Swift Programming Language" reference book (on Language Guide > Properties > Type Properties):

> “For value types (that is, structures and enumerations), you can define stored and computed type properties. For classes, you can define computed type properties only.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/br/jEUH0.l

But a couple of pages after this, the following code snippet can be found:

```
...
class SomeClass {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        // return an Int value here
    }
    class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
        // return an Int value here
    }
}
...
```

Where a stored type property is clearly defined inside a class context, which apparently negates what was stated earlier.

So, is this a documentation error or am I just missing something?

**Edit 1**

I don't feel like this is a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029581/why-no-stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift). I'm not asking why this functionality is not implemented, because apparently it is currently implemented (since the compiler won't identify it as an error). All I'm asking is if the documentation os out of date or my interpretation is incorrect.

**Edit 2**

This issue was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243013/stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift). Apparently the documentation is out of date. This functionality was added on Swift 1.2

Comment: I assume that Apple did not updated the book. Correct me if I am wrong. I was curios and checked it my self. This code works just fine: `class Test { static var someInt = 0 } print(Test.someInt)`

Comment: I am not sure it I understand your question correctly. Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243013/stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift ?

Comment: @GabrielHuff: You explained why you think that it is not a duplicate of [Why no stored type properties for classes in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029581/why-no-stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift). But unless I misunderstand your question (after the last edit), it is a duplicate of [Stored type properties for classes in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243013/stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift).

Comment: Ok, you are right. The second question addresses the same issue. So apparently the documentation is out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what the documentation meant (in a rather confusing way) is that you cannot have `class` stored vars (while you can still have `static` stored vars).

So, to summarize

```
class Foo {
  static var bar: Int {      // ok (computed static type variable)
    return 2
  }
  static var foo = ""        // ok (stored static type variable)
  class var foobar: Int {    // ok (computed class type variable)
    return 2
  }
  class var baz = ""         // nope (stored class type variable)
}
```

Comment: The final paragraph in `Type Property Syntax` lead me to the same conclusion.

Comment: I've seen somewhere on stackoverflow that `static` is just implicit typealias for `class final`, but this won't work here. Read here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29588815/4572536

Comment: That would make sense. But I think it's more likely to be an error, since the concept of `static` and `class` are only introduced on the next page. Also, by reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029581/why-no-stored-type-properties-for-classes-in-swift (which people think I'm duplicating) I assume that on earlier versions it wouldn't be possible to declare a stored type variable inside a class